# Подключение целей Yandex Metrika на Vue(NuxtJs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, яндекс-метрика

Как правильно подключить цели яндекс метрике в проекте на NuxtJs.
Последовательность моих действий:

1. Создал в static файл JS с метрикой (Уже здесь в консоль пытаюсь вызвать registGoal, выдает undefined)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Подключил данный файл в nuxt-config
3. Яндекс метрика подключилась
4. Таким способом привязываю на кнопки цели[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примечание: Пытался яндекс метрику подключать в plugins, для того, чтобы функция registGoal была глобальной и к ней можно было обращаться, но всё так же безрезультатно, мне кажется проблема начинается в пункте 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный способ подключения:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/views#document-apphtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>

  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}

    {% if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { %}
        <!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
        <script type="text/javascript" >
          // код скрипта
        </script>
        <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
    {% } %}
  </body>
</html>
```